# How can I save each match in a different file with Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to save the output of `g/pattern1/,/pattern2/` to a file (for each match, a different file).

e.g.

```
def
.......
end

def
.......
end
```

you would end up with a file for each "def...end".

Tried using tempname() like so:

`g/pattern1/,/pattern2/exe 'w ' . tempname()` but this fails with no range allowed for `exe`

also tried

```
g/pattern1/,/pattern2/w `tempname()`
```

to get tempname() evaluated but this failed with a "too many filenames" error.

What am I missing? Can this be done by using global and other commands, or would you need vimscript to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g/pattern1/,/pattern2/execute "w ".fnameescape(tempname())<CR>
```

Use `execute` whenever you want to insert variable into command-line if it is a mapping. If it is not, try using

```
g/pattern1/,/pattern2/w <C-r>=fn<Tab>e<Tab>te<Tab>)<CR><CR>
```

Here `fn<Tab>` with `wildmode=longest,list:full` will expand to `fname`, `fnamee<Tab>` will expand to `fnameescape(`, `te<Tab>` will expand to `tempname()`, so this is a short way to input `<C-r>=fnameescape(tempname())<CR>`. You can omit `fnameescape` if you are sure that `tempname` will not return filename with special characters.

And note that backticks will not execute vimscript function, they execute shell command, so `` `tempname()` `` tries to call `tempname()` in a shell and substitute filename with the result of this call. According to the help, you should have written `` `=tempname()` ``.

Comment: I forgot about the `=` inside the backticks. now `=tempname()` works as expected. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `` :g/pattern1/normal! :.,/pattern2/w `tempname()`^M `` with `^M` entered as CTRL-V then ENTER

Comment: nope. still get `too many filenames`. I am on Windows by the way, in case this is some OS related behaviour.